# Camel K: How can i define a datasource, which can be used in the Camel K JDBC Component or the Camel K SQL Component?

Tags: sql, kubernetes, apache-camel, datasource

I'm currently working on a project in Germany, which is already using Camel inside Karaf. And i would like to deploy an sample Camel route written in Blueprint XML inside a Kubernetes cluster using Camel K. Defining and creating the datasource was simple in Karaf. On Karaf CLI
just execute:

karaf@root()> jdbc:ds-create -t derby -u test -i datasource01

And then deploy below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
    http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

    <bean id="datasource01" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:database01" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="datasource02" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:database02" />
    </bean>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route>
            <...>
            <to uri="jdbc:datasource01"/>
            <...>
            <to uri="jdbc:datasource02"/>
            <...>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

I have searched the documentations and web for Camel K and Kubernetes datasources and haven't found the solution. Does anybody know how the datasource which is used in the JDBC Componenent URI can be created using Camel K inside Kubernetes ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I think apache camel expects that the datasource is already present.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow

You basically ask **how to define custom beans inside the Camel context** in Camel K. Datasource definitions etc are defined as beans in the Camel context.

See [this link](https://github.com/apache/camel-k/issues/814) for a similar question and an example answer.